# Animation in jQuery displays wrong images first cycle?

Tags: jquery

I have been experimenting with a jquery script that I found on the following link:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/simple-auto-playing-slideshow/

The running example does work, but if I run the code in my own VS 2010 project  for some reason the first image seems to revert back onto itself.

What I mean is the following:

Here are the images in default.aspx page:

```
    <div id="slideshow">
       <div>
         <img src="Images/boating.gif" width="240px" height="240px">
       </div>
       <div>
        <img src="Images/Cat.gif" width="240px" height="240px">
       </div>
       <div>
        <img src="Images/catcute.jpg" width="240px" height="240px">
       </div>
       <div>
        <img src="Images/cutebird.jpg" width="240px" height="240px">
       </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the code in my Default.js file :

```
   $(document).ready(function(){ 

$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide(); 

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first') 
    .fadeOut(1000) 
    .next() 
    .fadeIn(1000) 
    .end() 
    .appendTo('#slideshow'); 
},  3000); 

});
```

Here is the code in the style sheet file:

```
#slideshow {
    margin: 50px auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    padding: 10px;

}

#slideshow > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
}
```

Here is the code reference in my default.js file inside my default.aspx page:

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <script src="Default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</asp:Content>
```

Thank you in advance and kind regards
_geoNeo

Comment: Did you add the same styles they give you to your project as well, either inside a style block in the html file or preferably in a linked stylesheet?

Comment: Works fine: http://jsbin.com/itiwev/edit#javascript,html

Comment: I just ran the exact code that's given on the webiste into a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unyQk/) and it works like advertised.  You must be missing something in your CSS or your actual code for the images is incorrect.  Post your actual code rather than basic "img 1", "img 2" snippets.  It's something other than the JS you posted that's causing the error

Comment: hi all thank you for the replies I have added the code as they are in my test application - kind regards _geoNeo

Comment: IN your html i think a div is missing..

Comment: oops sorry uber i didnt paste the code correctly there is a closing div on the images - sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your entire code in

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() {
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  3000);

});
```

Comment: yep tried it again the "cutebird" image keeps coming up after each image. Once all the images has been stepped trough it seems fix itself - odd.

Comment: hi all i found the prob it was in my jquery ubercool - i had only wrap this in ready function: $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();   }); thanx :D

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code in a ready function:

```
    $(function() {

        $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

        setInterval(function() {
          $('#slideshow > div:first')
            .fadeOut(1000)
            .next()
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .end()
            .appendTo('#slideshow');
        },  3000);

    });
```

Working jsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/P3fEp/

Comment: Hi there paul I changed the code as you suggested above and still does the same thing "the cutebird" image keeps poping up after each image. Honestly dont know what doing wrong